# Pass/Redirect Inbound Traffic to a client inside the private network

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server with IP: x.x.x.x
I have a local server with a local IP of y.y.y.y and I would like to access its resources (http, ssh etc..) from the internet through the VPN so I have created a profile for the server and it's connected with an IP of 10.8.0.2
All of the local server traffic is being passed through the VPN, as when I do whatsmyip from the local server it shows x.x.x.x

My question is, how can I access the local server (all ports that are inbound requests should go directly to the local server) from the internet without using DDNS, I have a VPN server so it makes things even easier and more manageable. I can set an A record for some local wiki page for example, create a local email server and get it exposed etc.

I know it is something that has to do with IPTABLES, routing natting masquerade etc..
can someone help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked pretty fine:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:443
```

eth0 is a physical interface of the OVPN server, so i want all the inbound traffic to from eth0 (public server IP) into the client server which is on 10.8.0.2 and that I had to specifcy every port i wanted to preroute.

I did that with port 22 and 80 as well:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:22
```

So whenever I do

```
ssh root@VPN_IP -p 2222
```

it will forward the ssh into the client server instead.